# ggplot2: Bar graph with vertical columns for continuous data

Tags: r, debugging, ggplot2, graphics

I am trying to make aa function to produce a large number of (vertical) bar graphs for income means by quartile for various groups. I want my quartile columns to be individually named with their column names in the dataframe.

This makes my test data:

```
quart_nms <- c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th")
tile_nms <- function(vec, nms){
  if (length(vec) != length(nms)) stop(
    "length vec ", length(vec), " must equal length nms ", length(nms))
  out <- data.frame(t(unlist(vec)))
  colnames(out)<- nms
  out
}
t1 <- tile_nms(1:4, quart_nms)
```

This is my function. I understand, I think, that ggplot2 wants data in wide format for a chart of this type, but I suspect I am not passing  the list of variables correctly. Should they not be the y values?

```
bar_plot <- function(.dt, .tit="U.S. Personal Income Distribution by Quartile",
                     .sub = NULL, .xl = "Income Quartiles", .yl = "Mean Income", 
                     ...){
  ggplot(data =.dt) + 
    geom_col(mapping = aes(y = list(1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th)), stat = identity) +
    labs(title = .tit, subtitle = .sub)
}

gr1 <- bar_plot(.dt = t1, .sub = "pop subgroup name")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you think ggplot2 wants data in wide format. That's never the case. Once you convert into long format and make a few changes to your plotting function things work just fine.

This is from your code, unchanged:

```
quart_nms <- c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th")
tile_nms <- function(vec, nms){
  if (length(vec) != length(nms)) stop(
    "length vec ", length(vec), " must equal length nms ", length(nms))
  out <- data.frame(t(unlist(vec)))
  colnames(out)<- nms
  out
}
t1 <- tile_nms(1:4, quart_nms)
```

What follows is my code, based on yours:

```
# needed libraries
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# convert to long format
tlong <- gather(t1, quartile, value)
tlong$quartile <- factor(tlong$quartile, levels = quart_nms) # make factor and put levels in the right order

# plotting function
bar_plot <- function(.dt, .tit="U.S. Personal Income Distribution by Quartile",
                     .sub = NULL, .xl = "Income Quartiles", .yl = "Mean Income", 
                     ...){
  ggplot(data =.dt) + 
    geom_col(mapping = aes(x = quartile, y = value)) +
    labs(title = .tit, subtitle = .sub, x = .xl, y = .yl)
}

# call plotting function with long-format data
bar_plot(.dt = tlong, .sub = "pop subgroup name")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Claus! That's spectacular. I thought I had some example that said wide format was needed for bar charts of continuous variables, Maybe it was true in a very old version of ggplot2? Or maybe I dreamed them.